# Html2Canvas no body background image?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html2canvas

I'm working on a project where you can make a avatar and take a screenshot of him. the only problem is that the body background is  not showing in my screenshot. can anybody help?

this is my code:

```
function saveCanvas(){
  html2canvas(document.querySelector('#shot')).then(canvas => {
      html2canvas(document.getElementById('bodyy'), { letterRendering: 1, allowTaint : true, onrendered : function (canvas) { } });
      taintTest: false
      const a = document.createElement('a');
      document.body.appendChild(a);
      a.href = canvas.toDataURL();
      a.download = 'BitAvater.jpeg'
      a.click();
      window.location.href= result;
  });
}
```

and this is how I choose my background

```
function achtergrond5() {
    document.body.style.background = "url('../Images/background5.jpg') no-repeat ";
    document.body.style.backgroundSize = "100%";
}
```

Comment: it is because you are only saving `canvas`. The `body` would be behind `canvas`

Comment: Can you show the relevant HTML - we don't know what #shot is - is it the id of body or of a separate element?